# Exception thrown when opening internal browser

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

When I am trying to open internal web browser using

```
IWorkbenchBrowserSupport browserSupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport();
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to instantiate browser supportStatus ERROR: 
org.eclipse.equinox.registry code=1 Plug-in "XXXXX" was unable to instantiate 
class "org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WorkbenchBrowserSupport". 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
  Class org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI can not access a member of class org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WorkbenchBrowserSupport with modifiers "private"
```

Any idea why I get this error? Searching for error produced little hints. Debugging it shows that as error says private method is accessed through reflection.

Comment: What version of SWT are you using..? Try to update to last one, or if you are using it then downgrade to last stable..

Comment: What is the platform you're working at?

Comment: @Sorceror Running in 3.7 TP it's 3.7.2.v3740f and in 3.5 it's 3.5.2v3557f. Happens on both 3.7 and 3.5, on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Looks like real OSGI bug.. You might post it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Filed bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399506